# react native 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libfbjni.so' from inputs

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I am getting this error since yesterday while running react native app and absolutely no changes were made which is crazy. I have wasted so many hours so decided to ask here. Already tried `gradle clean` and also deleting .gradle and build folders. Please check the error below -

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libfbjni.so' from inputs:
  - C:\Users\DELL\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\fec30cdec6405e4005c100e8efa899d0\transformed\jetified-react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug\jni\arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so
  - C:\Users\DELL\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\09bb94ee0a520d6ded1278936c1d07c7\transformed\jetified-fbjni-0.3.0\jni\arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so
 If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
 https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets
```

In Mac it gives the following error -

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#automatic_packaging_of_prebuilt_dependencies_used_by_cmake
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to add the following in your `android/build.gradle` file.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
   exclusiveContent {
       // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
       // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
       // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
       // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
       filter {
           includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
       }
       forRepository {
           maven {
               url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
           }
       }
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

What this fix will do is apply an `exclusiveContent` resolution rule that will force the resolution of React Native Android library, to use the one inside `node_modules`.

Once you update your app to React Native `v0.71.0`, this fix won't be needed anymore.
Reason - The reason is very briefly explained here - [Fix and updates on Android build failures](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

UPDATE - This also fixes issue with kotlin due to the same reason

```
Incompatible classes were found in dependencies.
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
```

UPDATE - React Native team has pushed hotfix releases for all the main versions of react-native as below:

0.70.5: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.70.5

️ 0.69.7: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.69.7

0.68.5: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.68.5

️ 0.67.5: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.67.5

️ 0.66.5: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.66.5

️ 0.65.3: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.65.3

️ 0.64.4: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.64.4

️ 0.63.5: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.63.5

By updating to these patch versions in your `package.json`, your Android build should start working again.

Comment: After applying this workaround, Im getting this new errror, even after gradlew clean: Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @AugustoSamaméBarrientos please add some details so i can understand more 
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210#issuecomment-1306591506 @Faizal Shap

Comment: Please check if you have `android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true` in `gradle. properties` file @AugustoSamaméBarrientos

Comment: Thanks! Yes, both values are there and are true. @Faizal Shap

Comment: Love you bro save my days